# Grading Form Using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to make a .NET grade form using C# and the issue that I am having is that the average that I am getting is wrong. Even though I tried to calculate the total in many different loops it just does not get the sum correct. Sometime it is too high sometimes it is too low. When I tried calculating the total marks in the validation loop it shows some weird sum of high value and when I tried to calculate the total in calculate function the sum comes out too low. Please help!

```
namespace SemesterGradesForm
{
    public partial class formSemesterGrades : Form
    {
        TextBox[] inputTextBoxes;
        TextBox[] outputTextBoxes;
        double totalMarks;

        public formSemesterGrades()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            inputTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBoxCourse1Marks, textBoxCourse2Marks, textBoxCourse3Marks, textBoxCourse4Marks, textBoxCourse5Marks, textBoxCourse6Marks, textBoxCourse7Marks };
            outputTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBoxCourse1LetterGrade, textBoxCourse2LetterGrade, textBoxCourse3LetterGrade, textBoxCourse4LetterGrade, textBoxCourse5LetterGrade, textBoxCourse6LetterGrade, textBoxCourse7LetterGrade };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare a given numeric grade value to an array of grades to determine a letter representing that grade. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numericGrade"> A grde between 0 and 100</param>
        /// <returns>Letter grade as a short string</returns>
        private string GetLetterGrade(double numericGrade)
        {
            // Declare arrays for the grade values and letter values that corresponds.
            double[] gradeValues = { 0D, 50D, 52D, 58D, 60D, 62D, 68D, 70D, 72D, 78D, 80D, 82D, 90D };
            string[] gradeLetters = { "F", "D-", "D", "D+", "C-", "C", "C+", "B-", "B", "B+", "A-", "A", "A+" };
            // Default the return letter to F
            string returnLetter = "F";

            // Count through the array comparing grades to the input grade.
            for (int counter = 0; counter < gradeValues.Length; counter++)
            {
                // if the niput grade is bigger than the value in the array, assign the letter grade.
                if (numericGrade > gradeValues[counter])
                {
                    returnLetter = gradeLetters[counter];
                }
                // If the input grade is not bigger than the value in the arraym return the last assigned letter grade
                else
                {
                    return returnLetter;
                }
            }
            return returnLetter;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if a passed TexBox is a numeric grade between 0 and 100
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="boxToCheck"> A textbox to check for a valid numeric grade value</param>
        /// <returns> true if valid </returns>
        private bool IsTextBoxValid(TextBox boxToCheck)
        {
            const double MinimumGrade = 0.0;
            const double MaximumGrade = 100.0;
            double gradeValue = 0;

            if (double.TryParse(boxToCheck.Text, out gradeValue))
            {
                if (gradeValue >= MinimumGrade && gradeValue <= MaximumGrade)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears fields and sets the form to its default state
        /// </summary>
        private void SetDefaults()
        {
            // Clear All input controls.
            ClearControls(inputTextBoxes);

            //Clear all output controls.
            ClearControls(outputTextBoxes);
            textBoxSemesterMarks.Clear();
            textBoxSemesterLetterGrade.Clear();
            textBoxOutput.Clear();
            
            // Reset variable
            totalMarks = 0;

            //Set focus in some useful way
            textBoxCourse1Marks.Focus();

            // Re-enable controls
            buttonCalculate.Enabled = true;
            SetControlsEnabled(inputTextBoxes, true);
        
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Mass clears the text boxes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controlArray">An array of controls with a text property to clear</param>
        private void ClearControls(Control[] controlArray)
        {
            foreach (Control controlToClear in controlArray)
            {
                controlToClear.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: You should comment this - what does it do?
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controlArray">An array of controls to enable or disable</param>
        /// <param name="enabledStatus">true to enable, false to disable</param>
        private void SetControlsEnabled(Control[] controlArray, bool enabledStatus)
        {
            foreach (Control controlToSet in controlArray)
            {
                controlToSet.Enabled = enabledStatus;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// When youn leave one of the textboxes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void LeaveInputTextbox (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Count through all of the textboxes.
            for( int inputCounter = 0; inputCounter < inputTextBoxes.Length; inputCounter++ )
            {

                // Determine if the textbox's contents are valid.
                if (IsTextBoxValid(inputTextBoxes[inputCounter]))
                {
                    double grade;

                    // Get the letter grade from this textbox
                    grade = double.Parse(inputTextBoxes[inputCounter].Text);

                    // Assign this letter grade to the corresponding label.
                    outputTextBoxes[inputCounter].Text = GetLetterGrade(grade);

                }
            }
        }

        private void formSemesterGrades_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetDefaults();
        }

        private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double averageMarks = 0;
            int invalidBox = 0;
            int validBox = 0;
            for (int inputCounter = 0; inputCounter < inputTextBoxes.Length; inputCounter++)
            {
                if (IsTextBoxValid(inputTextBoxes[inputCounter]))
                {
                    totalMarks += double.Parse(inputTextBoxes[inputCounter].Text);
                    // Increase counter
                    inputCounter++;
                    // If the textbox is valid, count it. If not, just don't.
                    validBox++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the box is not blank, increment the number of invalid boxes by one.
                    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputTextBoxes[inputCounter].Text) == false)
                    {
                        // Focus on invalid input
                        inputTextBoxes[inputCounter].Focus();
                        textBoxOutput.Text = "Please enter VALID Values!";
                        // Increase invalid counter
                        invalidBox++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If number of valid boxes == 1 && number of invalid boxes == 0
            if (validBox >= 1 && invalidBox == 0)
            {
                // Calculate and output the average
                averageMarks = Math.Round(totalMarks / inputTextBoxes.Length, 2);

                // Display the Average marks and grade
                textBoxSemesterMarks.Text = averageMarks.ToString();

                // Assign this letter grade to the corresponding label.
                double grade;
                grade = double.Parse(textBoxSemesterMarks.Text);
                textBoxSemesterLetterGrade.Text = GetLetterGrade(grade);

                // Disable input controls until the form is reset.
                buttonCalculate.Enabled = false;
                SetControlsEnabled(inputTextBoxes, false);
                buttonReset.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxOutput.Text = "Please enter VALID Values!";
            }
        }

        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `inputCounter` when a text box is valid and its value was added to `totalMarks`? The `for` loop already does that.

Comment: You should probably reset `totalMarks` to `0.0` in the beginning of `buttonCalculate_Click()`.

Comment: [You posted too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). You haven't [provided debugging details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Both are symptoms of [doing no debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). You have to do that first.

Comment: **[Debugging your code using the  built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** is easier than you think.

Comment: In the spirit of OOP you should create a class to handle the grading logic separate from your UI. Doing the calculations in a button click handler is always a code smell.

Comment: Good Night Nerd Pride thank you, I found it yesterday after using the debugger as suggested by some people in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have posted too much code, as the question pertains to the calculation of the class average grade.

Fundamentally, you are storing the grades as strings inside UI elements (such as text boxes) and therefore cannot directly interact with the data unless you keep converting from strings to values all the time.

I suggest you create a C# object (a class) to store the class grades named `Class` and have it handle all the logic. In this case, you can use the built-in `.Average()` method as part of `System.Linq` which returns the average of any collection of numbers.

In my example below I produces the following output:

```
Class: Art I
---
     Student    Score    Grade
        Alex       48        F
    Beatrice       56        D
      Claire       65        C
      Dennis       78       B+
      Eugene       82        A
      Forest       88        A
        Gwen       98       A+
---
     Average     73.6        B
```

from the following sample code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var art = new Class("Art I",
            "Alex", "Beatrice", "Claire",
            "Dennis", "Eugene", "Forest",
            "Gwen");

        art.SetGrade("Alex", 48m);
        art.SetGrade("Beatrice", 56m);
        art.SetGrade("Claire", 65m);
        art.SetGrade("Dennis", 78m);
        art.SetGrade("Eugene", 82m);
        art.SetGrade("Forest", 88m);
        art.SetGrade("Gwen", 98m);

        Console.WriteLine($"Class: {art.Title}");
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Student",12} {"Score",8} {"Grade",8}");
        foreach (var grade in art.Grades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{grade.Key,12} {grade.Value,8} {Class.GetLetterGrade(grade.Value),8}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Average",12} {art.AverageScore,8} {Class.GetLetterGrade(art.AveragScore),8}");
    }
```

The key here is the methods `Class.AverageScore` and the letter scores which depend on the static function `Class.GetLetterGrade()`.

The actual logic is handled by the `Class` object defined as

```
public class Class
{
    public Class(string title, params string[] students)
    {
        Title = title;
        grades = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            grades[student] = 0m;
        }
    }

    public string Title { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Students { get => grades.Keys.ToList(); }

    public void SetGrade(string student, decimal score)
    {
        if (grades.ContainsKey(student))
        {
            this.grades[student] = score;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Student not found", nameof(student));
        }
    }

    readonly Dictionary<string, decimal> grades;
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, decimal> Grades { get => grades; }
    
    public decimal AverageScore { get => Math.Round(grades.Values.Average(),1); }

    #region Grading
    // Declare arrays for the grade values and letter values that corresponds.
    static readonly decimal[] gradeValues = {  0,   50,   52,  58,   60,   62,  68,   70,   72,  78,   80,   82,  90 };
    static readonly string[] gradeLetters = { "F", "D-", "D", "D+", "C-", "C", "C+", "B-", "B", "B+", "A-", "A", "A+" };
    public static string GetLetterGrade(decimal score)
    {
        // use rounding rules
        score = Math.Round(score, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        if (score > 100m) { score = 100m; } // max 100
        int index = Array.IndexOf(gradeValues, gradeValues.LastOrDefault((x) => score >= x));
        if (index < 0) { index = 0; }   // default "F"
        return gradeLetters[index];
    }
    public static decimal GetScoreFromLetter(string grade)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(gradeLetters, grade);
        if (index <= 0) { index = 0; }  // default "0"
        return gradeValues[index];
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Notice that I chose to use `decimal` to score grades instead of `double` as the nature of `double` makes it harder for comparisons and display. This avoids results like `84.9999999999997` instead of `85.0`.